# Add baseHref to sourceLocale of Angular i18n

Tags: angular

I need to define a baseHref to my default languagem wroted in my angular code, if I wrote in Portugueses.

I want to serve angular ("ng serve --configuration=pt") and have router like "http://localhost:4200/pt", that same for "ng serve --configuration=en" serve in "http://localhost:4200/en".

the "baseHref" define in "sourceLocale" is not working to angular 17

```
  "i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": {
      "baseHref": "/my-base-href/",
      "code": "pt-BR"
    },
    "locales": {
      "en": {
        "translation": "src/translation/messages-en.json",
        "baseHref": "en/"
      },
    }
  },
```

I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

'pt' is my default language using in my source code

```
run "ng serve --configuration=pt" ===> this http://localhost:4200/pt
run "ng serve --configuration=en" ===> this http://localhost:4200/en
```

don't define 'pt' in locales, because your angular was already wrote at this language, so is not necessary translate it.

```
"i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": "pt-BR", //langage default that your angular was wrote
    "locales": { //languages that you want to translate your default language 
      "en": {
        "translation": "src/translation/messages-en.json",
        "baseHref": "en/"
      },
    }
  },
```

here is used to build angular to production environment, in architect > build you can define config to languages and the default 'pt', but not define "localize" propertie to your default language, because it not exist.

```
 "configurations": {
        "production": {
           ...
        },
        "development": {
           ...
        },
        "pt": {
          "baseHref": "/bwp/app/home/pt/" **<= not define localize here**
        },
        "en": {
          "localize": ["en"],
          "baseHref": "/bwp/app/home/en/"
        },
      },
```

here is to server angular to development environment

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          ...
        },
        "development": {
          ...
        },
        "pt": {
          "buildTarget": "bwp_app_home:build:development,pt"
        },
        "en": {
          "buildTarget": "bwp_app_home:build:development,en"
        },
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
```

Now you can run to server or build configurating this code in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "bwp-app-home[server-dev-pt]": "ng serve --configuration=pt",
    "bwp-app-home[server-dev-en]": "ng serve --configuration=en",
    "bwp-app-home[build-prod]": "ng build"
}
```